# If file extension is .xls, then MsgBox

Tags: vba, excel, file-extension

I have written a VBA script that performs different sorting/matching/filtering functions for a client with a large amount of data (anywhere from 45,000 to 500,000 rows).

The issue is, if the user exports or saves this data as, say, an `.xls` file, only 65,536 rows will be saved which would be potentially insufficient.  On execution of the script, I'd like a `MsgBox` to appear IF the user "mistakenly" exports the data as an `.xls` file, else continue.

I've tried the code below in order to see if I can even get the file extension properly, but my `MsgBox` isn't returning anything:

```
Sub ext()

Dim extFind As String
Dim sFile As String

    Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    sFile = Dir(FilePath & Filename & "*")
    extFind = Right$(sFile, Len(sFile) - InStrRev(sFile, "."))
    MsgBox extFind
End Sub
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're going to add a check like this for user experience, I would say first check to see whether there are 65k rows of data used. If the rows are less than 65k, then I wouldn't bring up a confirmation box which implies data could be lost, when it wouldnt.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon that's an excellent point. I'll have to write that in. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FileSystemObject` library has a `GetExtensionName()` function to make life easier:

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strExt = .GetExtensionName(ActiveWorkbook.Path)
End With

If StrComp(strExt, "xls", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
    ' Display error
End If
```

Or, you could just check the number of rows in the workbook:

```
If ActiveSheet.Rows.Count = 65536 Then
    ' Display error
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss a slash between `FilePath` and `Filename`:

```
sFile = Dir(FilePath & "\" & Filename & "*")
```

By the way, where do you assign value to variable `Filename`? If you meant to use the name of the active workbook you should use `ActiveWorkbook.Name`.

Comment: I knew it was something simple. Thanks!